# Difference between 谷 and 谷間?

Tags: word-choice

I noticed that 谷{たに} and 谷間{たにま} both mean valley in the dictionary. However, when I Google 谷間, I get a bunch of pictures of cleavage.

Should only 谷 be used to describe "valley"? And, can 谷間 also mean valley but is basically slang for cleavage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think 谷 is commonly only used to describe "valley".

However 谷間 has a meaning other than "valley". It is used when you describe low place between high places. For example. 胸の谷間(It is cleavage, isn't it?), ビルの谷間、景気の谷間.

Answer (score 1):

Probably we say 谷 for a valley as a whole, and 谷間 to focus on the bottom of a valley.